# Filtrar elementos de uma lista em Python

Tags: python

Galera estou querendo remover todos números iguais a 1, mas está dando este erro

> list index out of range

Segue o programa

```
lista= [2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15, 1, 1]

qtd = len(lista)


for i in range(qtd):     

    if(lista[i]==1):
        lista.remove(lista[i])
        print("Removeu")
        print(lista)

    qtd = qtd - 1


print("Final",lista)
```

Comment: Por quê fazer `qtd = qtd - 1`? Qual a lógica que você imaginou?

Comment: Porque o tamanho da lista estava sendo imutavel. Por exemplo a lista tem 11 elementos e no "for" seria sempre 11, mas quando entrasse no if era para decrementar o tamanho e atualizar no "for". Porque quando entra no if remove um elemento

Comment: Exatamente. É por isso que você não pode fazer da maneira que tentou fazer. Você não pode iterar sobre o objeto que está sendo mudado dentro do `for`. Tem como fazer copiando o objeto e iterando sobre a cópia, mas as opções que citei na resposta são muito mais elegantes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Resposta está um tanto desatualizada e carece de alguns detalhes adicionais. Corrigi o que estava mais grotesco e a noite irei reescrevê-la.*

Você pode filtrar sua lista de 3 formas possíveis:

1. Utilizando a função `filter`
2. Utilizando *list comprehensions*
3. Utilizando *generators*

## Função `filter`

Adiantando a resposta, você pode tirar proveito das ferramentas que a linguagem te ofecere. Como você quer fazer um filtro sobre os valores de uma lista, nada melhor que utilizar a função [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) do Python:

```
>>> lista = [2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15, 1, 1]
>>> lista = list(filter(lambda x: x != 1, lista))
>>> print(lista)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15]
```

#### [Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Retorna um objeto iterável contendo os valores de segundo parâmetro cujo a execução de `function` sobre o mesmo retorne `True`.

```
iterable filter(function, iterable)
```

Ou seja, ao fazermos:

```
filter(myFilter, lista)
```

Será retornado <strike>todos os valores</strike> um gerador de `lista` no qual `myFilter(x)`, sendo `x` o elemento de `lista`, retorne verdadeiro. Como desejas filtrar os valores iguais a 1, basta ter a condição: `x != 1`. Foi utilizado a função `lambda` **devido a simplicidade da função**, mas nada impede de fazer:

```
>>> lista = [2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15, 1, 1] 
>>> def is_not_one (value):
...   return value != 1
>>> lista = list(filter(is_not_one, lista))
>>> print(lista)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15]
```

O resultado é exatamente o mesmo.

**Quando utilizar?**

A função `filter` é ideal para ser utilizada quando a lógica do filtro não é tão trivial (que não dê para escrever em uma linha de código).

**Teste básico**:

```
import random, time, sys

SIZE = 1000000

# Gera-se dados aleatórios entre 0 e 1
lista = [random.randrange(0, 9) for _ in range(SIZE)]

# Filtra a lista através de compressão de listas

START_TIME = time.time()

# Filtra a listra através da função `filter`

list_filter = filter(lambda i: i != 1, lista)

FILTER_TIME = time.time()

print("Execução em: ", FILTER_TIME - START_TIME)
print("Consumo em memória: ", sys.getsizeof(list_filter))
```

Saída:

```
Execução em:  5.9604644775390625e-06
Consumo em memória:  56
```

---

## *List Comprehensions*

Como [respondido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190098/5878) pelo usuário Camilo Santos:

```
>>> lista = [2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15, 1, 1]
>>> lista = [l for l in lista if l != 1]
>>> print(lista) 
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15]
```

**Quando utilizar?**

É ideal utilizar as *list comprehensions* quando o número de elementos da lista é pequeno e a lógica de filtro é trivial (que pode ser escrito em uma linha). A nova lista será armazenada por completo na memória e, com isso, pode consumir muito recurso da máquina se a mesma for muito extensa.

**Teste básico:**

```
import random, time, sys

SIZE = 1000000

# Gera-se dados aleatórios entre 0 e 1
lista = [random.randrange(0, 9) for _ in range(SIZE)]

# Filtra a lista através de compressão de listas

START_TIME = time.time()

list_comprehension = [i for i in lista if i != 1]

LIST_TIME = time.time()

print("Execução em: ", LIST_TIME - START_TIME)
print("Consumo em memória: ", sys.getsizeof(list_comprehension))
```

Saída:

```
Execução em:  0.05048513412475586
Consumo em memória:  7731040
```

Consome memória e tempo de execução, por isso deve ser utilizada com cautela.

---

## *Generator*

Utilizando a ferramenta de geradores do Python:

```
>>> def filter_by_generator(lista, value):
...   for i in lista:
...     if i != value: yield i
>>> lista = filter_by_generator(lista, 1)
>>> print(list(lista))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15]
```

**Quando utilizar?**

Os *generators* devem ser utilizados quando o número de elementos na lista é muito grande, independente de quão complexa é a lógica do filtro (se for simples, pode utilizar `filter` e reduzir o código).

**Teste básico:**

```
import random, time, sys

SIZE = 1000000

# Gera-se dados aleatórios entre 0 e 1
lista = [random.randrange(0, 9) for _ in range(SIZE)]

START_TIME = time.time()

# Filtra a lista através de gerador

def filter_by_generator(lista, value):
  for i in lista:
    if i != value: yield i

lista_generator = filter_by_generator(lista, 1)

GENERATOR_TIME = time.time()

print("Execução em: ", GENERATOR_TIME - START_TIME)
print("Consumo em memória: ", sys.getsizeof(lista_generator))
```

Saída:

```
Execução em:  4.291534423828125e-06
Consumo em memória:  88
```

Tanto tempo de execução quanto espaço em memória são muito inferiores aos demais métodos. Isso acontece porque o *generator* não computa toda a lista de uma vez, mas gera cada item da lista em "tempo real" quando a mesma é iterada.

Answer (score 6):

Também pode ser utilizado **[List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**, ele consome menos recursos da máquina do que o filter() ou map(), mas o resultado é exatamente o mesmo.

```
lista = [2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15, 1, 1]
lista = [l for l in lista if l != 1]
print(lista) #A saída será: [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15]
```