# Compreensão de lista com condicional

Tags: python, lista

Meu objetivo é contabilizar quantos elementos de uma determinada lista correspondem a uma condição. Para tanto, fiz as seguintes linhas de código:

```
cont = 0
seq = []
max = 10
for x in seq if x == max:
    cont = cont+1
```

Entretanto, obtenho erro de sintaxe em `if x == max`. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Pode ler minha resposta sobre [como filtrar uma lista em Python](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190086/5878) para maiores informações. Obviamente que se a intenção é apenas contar a quantidade de elementos igual à `max`, o *mais pythonico* é `seq.count(max)` como comentado nas respostas.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459254/d%c3%a1-para-fazer-o-for-em-1-linha/459263#459263)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá.
A sintaxe utilizado pelo senhor em seu código encontra-se incorreta com base nos padrões da linguagem, e Python, um bloco é sempre delimitado por dois pontos **':'**  seguida de uma:

> quebra de linha com tabulação de 4 espaços já **predefinidos** pela IDE (que pode ser **modificada** de acordo com a **preferência do usuário**),

a sintaxe mais acessível com base em sua pergunta seria a que segue abaixo.

```
cont = 0
seq = [0 , 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 10, 10, 25]
max = 10
for x in seq:
    if x == max:
        cont = cont+1

op = int(input("DESEJA VERIFICAR O RESULTADO? DIGITE 1 PARA VISUALIZAR OU OUTRO VALOR PARA SAIR " ))
if op == 1:
    print("FORAM ENCONTRADOS %i valores" %(cont))
else:
    print()
```

Note que eu modifiquei o programa original e apliquei a opção de visualização, assim o usuário poderia escolher entre visualizar quantos valores estão entre as conformidades ou sair do programa.

Comment: Felix tens alguns pontos na resposta menos corretos. Em relação à tabulação nada diz que esta precisa ser 4 espaços, pode ser até apenas um espaço, ex: http://ideone.com/OX7Wt9 , desde que mantenhas a mesma em todo o programa. Também não tens a "obrigatoriadade" de mudar de linha (mas por convenção, sim, mudamos, e em alguns casos daria erro se não o fizesses), mas aqui tens o programa da minha resposta em uma linha: http://ideone.com/idB5wF

Comment: @Miguel - Sim, eu concordo sobre a tabulação, mas por convenção adotamos a tabulação de 4 espaços como default, isto já vem incluso nas IDEs.

Sobre o seu programa em uma única linha, você utilizou outros parâmetros para realizar esta proeza, mas para iniciantes o  básico é o simples, por isto citei isto.

Comment: sim, o que disseste é a convenção mas na resposta parece quereres dizer que é regra, fiz um reparo para que pudesses editar se quisesses, para não induzir outros em erro

Comment: @Miguel - Entendido então, levarei essa dica para as próximas respostas, para não confundir os demais XD

Comment: OI - sua sintaxe está incorreta, com uma identação "do nada" na segunda linha.

Comment: Sua resp'osta tambéme es'incorreta: Pyhton não exige que a identação  
seja de "4 espaços" - só precisa existir uma identação, que pode ser de qualquer número de espaços e/outabs. Por conveção de estilo se usa 4 espaços - mas o seu texto põe como se isso fosse parte da sintaxe.

Comment: @jsbueno - Obrigado, foi na hora de adicionar o pré-code, eu adicionei uma edentação a mais, obrigado pelo aviso XD, ainda estou me acostumando com o sistema do Stack

Comment: @jsbueno - Sobre a tabulação de 4 espaços, foi o que eu citei para o Miguel, por convenção, aceitamos a tabulação de 4 espaços em branco com uma certa facilidade, e com isto, a maioria dos editores de texto já vem com esta propriedade como Default, em termos simples, falar sobre a tabulação de 4 espaços pode ser referida a este motivo, não quer dizer que é obrigatório, mas é o mais utilizado e vem por default na IDE, e com isto pode ser facilmente modificada pelo usuário.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss - Está corrigido

Comment: O que o jsbueno quer dizer é que você pode deixar claro já na resposta que não existe a obrigatoriedade de ser 4 espaços, que é obrigatório apenas existir a indentação, mas que é utilizado 4 espaços em acordo com a [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) (Citar a PEP também seria interessante).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss- Certo, no futuro tomarei estas precações

Answer (score 5):

O `if` não pode estar na mesma linha do `for`.

```
cont = 0
seq = []
max = 10
for x in seq:
    if x == max:
        cont = cont + 1
print(cont)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Za8UYV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kbyycilk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ConditionalComprehension.py).

Answer (score 5):

Para contares os elementos de uma lista que satisfazem uma determinda condição, tendo em conta o titulo da pergunta ("compreensão de lista") podes fazer:

```
seq = [1,3,4,21,10,30,10,24]
max = 10
cont = len([x for x in seq if x == max]) # 2
```

Nota que para este propósito em específico (visto a condição ser igualdade, `==`) basta e aconselho fazer:

```
cont = seq.count(max)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/DSQjsR)

PS: Esse ocorre por teres o `if` na mesma linha do `for`, não é sintaxe correta para uma [compreensão de lista](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: Dado que o foco do AP é a resolução do problema (usando compreensões) e não necessariamente a mensagem de erro, eu diria que esta é a melhor resposta e deveria ser a aceita. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira olá, também acho. Tinha acabado de fazer o acrescento n.a resposta acerca do erro, foi mesmo no timing. Obgado (apaguei o comentário anterior porque me esqueci de responder diretamente ao que disse)

Comment: Por nada. Enfim, quem define mesmo qual é a melhor e deve ser aceita é o Vinícius, né? Eu só estava dando a minha opinião.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar uma compreensão de lista na qual possa contar a quantidade de vezes que o valor **"10"** se repeti na referida lista.

Pois bem, para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
print(len([x for x in list(map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split())) if x == 10]))
```

Observe que quando executamos o código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

A partir desse momento os valores capturados pelo `input()` serão armazenados em uma lista. Em seguida o bloco `for` percorrerá todos os elementos da referida lista e com ajuda do bloco `if` verificará se o valor de `x` é igual a `10`. Caso positivo, o valor será armazenado na lista. Posteriormente a função `len()` calculará o tamanho desta lista e exibirá a quantidade de valores `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Como os colegas já disseram faltam os dois pontos `:` após `for x in seq` e `if x == max` e python não permite que certos constructos sejam posicionados na mesma linha:

```
cont = 0
seq = [1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 77, 92, 10, 10]
max = 10
for x in seq:
  if x == max:
    cont = cont+1

print(cont)
```

Eu gostaria de sugerir uma outra abordagem, a programação funcional usando o módulo [functools](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html) que oferece funções que atuam em ou retornam outras funções.

No caso a solução usa a função [reduce()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) que possui a seguinte assinatura:

> `functools.reduce( função , iterável [ , inicializador ] )`
>
> Aplica a `função` de dois argumentos cumulativamente aos itens do iterável , da
> esquerda para a direita, de modo a reduzir o iterável a um único
> valor.
> Por exemplo, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calcula `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`.
> O argumento esquerdo, `x`, é o acumulador e o argumento direito, `y`, é um valor vindo do iterável.
> Se o inicializador opcional estiver presente, ele é colocado antes dos itens do iterável no cálculo e serve como padrão quando o iterável está vazio.
> Se o inicializador não for fornecido e o iterável contiver apenas um item, o primeiro item será retornado.

No exemplo foi utilizado uma [função lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) que compara um elemento `e` de `seq` com `max`. Se ambos forem iguais soma `1` ao acumulador `a` senão apenas devolve `a`:

```
from functools import reduce

seq = [1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 77, 92, 10, 10]
max = 10

cont = reduce(lambda a, v : a + (1 if v==max else 0), seq, 0)

print(cont)   #3
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/DistinctMobileApplicationprogram#main.py)</sup>