# Removendo elementos de uma lista em Python

Tags: python, lista

Basicamente eu quero remover os elementos de uma lista segundo um critério. Por exemplos: eu tenho uma sala com N alunos, eu vou armazenar a nota desses alunos em uma lista e comparar essas notas com a nota de corte que eu digitar. Se a nota do aluno for maior ou igual a nota de corte eu deixo ele na lista, caso contrário eu removo ele da lista

Comment: Mostre o que vc ja fez e com o que está tendo problema, especifique sua pergunta e lembre-se que StackOverflow não é um lugar pra pedir pras pessoas fazerem "tarefa" de faculdade/colegio.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado o título é quase o mesmo, mas os problemas são diferentes.

Comment: @DanielGomes verdade, vacilo meu. Essa daqui dá para ir com `list comprehension`

Answer (score 1):

> Somente depois do@AndersonCarlosWoss identificar que havia uma outra pergunta idêntica, vi que a resposta dele é muito mais ampla que a minha. Vide https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190086/64969

Use [compreensão de listas](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Seja `sala` uma lista de alunos. Seja aluno definido como tendo o atributo `nota`. Seja `corte` a variável da mota de corte. Então, podemos obter a lista de alunos aprovados da seguinte maneira:

```
aprovados = [ aluno for aluno in sala if aluno.nota >= corte ]
```

Assim, obtemos a lista de alunos aprovados de uma sala sem precisar alterar o valor original da lista da sala.

### EDIT

Minha leitura inicial do problema era de que se tinha uma lista de *alunos* que precisavam ser filtrados por *nota*, porém relendo a questão e, também, levando em conta o comentário do AP, percebi que se tem uma *lista de notas*. Meu código anterior continua com a forma válida, porém precisamos rever alguns dos conceitos utilizados.

Como estamos com uma lista de notas, não tenho objeto `aluno` com atributo `nota`, apenas um número que já indica a nota do aluno. Assim:

Seja `sala` uma lista de notas de alunos. Seja `corte` a variável da mota de corte. Então, podemos obter a lista de alunos aprovados da seguinte maneira:

```
notas_aprovadas = [ nota for nota in sala if nota >= corte ]
```

Comment: Eu estou declarando uma lista notas e a partir dela eu quero fazer isso. Tentei implementar seguindo sua lógica e não consegui

Comment: Você leu como eu estava assumindo que você chegava na nota do aluno? Eu tentou só copiar meu código?

Comment: Mais importante, você leu a resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss? Tanto ele postou como comentário como, logo após ele escrever o comentário de possível duplicação, eu editei minha resposta e relacionei com a resposta dele?