# Como descobrir números maiores que X numa lista

Tags: python

Como exemplo, esse código aí

```
N=[1,2,3,4,5]
B= #quantidade de números maiores que 2
print(B)
```

'B' seria a quantidade de números maiores que 2 presentes na lista, por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra simplificar você pode usar assim:

```
minha_lista = [1,2,3,4,5]
maior_que = 2

filtrados = [x for x in minha_lista if x > maior_que]

#exibe os elementos
print(filtrados)

#conta os elementos
print(len(filtrados))
```

Comment: Bem mais simplificado que a minha resposta, ainda estou a aprender, e muito.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza é uma das coisas que gosto em Python, estava relutante em migrar para o Python3.6 (eu estava "travado" no 2.7), mas tudo até agora tem me agradado, fico feliz de saber que você esta se interessando pela linguagem também :D

Answer (score 4):

A lógica é exatamente a mesma para filtrar elementos de uma lista:

[Filtrar elementos de uma lista em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190078/5878)

A mais simples e direta é utilizar a compreensão de listas:

```
B = len([i for i in N if i > 2])
```

Neste caso, utilizamos a função `len` para calcular a quantidade de elementos.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/we0dfr).

Outra forma, equivalente a compreensão de lista, é utilizar a função `filter`:

```
B = filter(lambda i: i > 2, N)
```

Porém, o retorno desta função será um gerador, necessitando assim a conversão para lista para obter-se seu comprimento:

```
B = len(list(filter(lambda i: i > 2, N)))
```

Mas para esta solução, este método se torna inviável comparado ao primeiro.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/FA6Ofo).

Answer (score 0):

Aqui uma solução, pode haver mais fácil e menor

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,23]
X = 0
B = 0 # Armazena a quantidade de números maiores que 2
num_elementos_lista = len(lista)
while(X < num_elementos_lista):
    if lista[X] > 2: # verifica se lista[X] é maior que 2
      B+=1 # Se for incrementa + 1 em B
    X+=1

print(B)
```

Veja funcionando no [repl](https://ideone.com/Yimczk)

Comment: Acredito que eu tenha entendido a sua ideia e ela não é de toda ruim, mas a implementação está errada. Substitua a lista por `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` e veja o que acontece. O resultado esperado é 0, mas... Veja se compreende o motivo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na verdade eu errei em algo na hora, estava verificando se `X` era maior que `2`, sendo que era para verificar `lista[X] > 2`

Comment: Perfeito, agora uma sugestão que tornaria sua solução mais [pythonica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878): para percorrer valores de uma lista evite utilizar o `while` com o `len`, pois é um vício de outras linguagens que não só é mal visto na comunidade como a performance é menor. Para tal, prefira utilizar `for n in lista`, onde nesse caso o `n` será os valores da lista, podendo fazer `if n > 2: ...`, não precisando mais do `len` ou da variável de controle `X`. Veja: https://ideone.com/8bghU2, que nada mais é que a compreensão de lista de forma expandida.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss interessante, vlw pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Se você pretende `apenas` saber a `quantidade` de valores maiores do que um determinado valor, que no caso é `2`, você pode implementar um laço de repetição e verificar a soma de todos os números maiores que `2`.

Para isso você pode implementar o seguinte código...

```
N = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cont = 0
for c in N:
    if c > 2:
        cont += 1

print(f'\033[32mA quantidade dos números maiores que "2" é: {cont}')
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/ypdptaxe-solkarped).

Observe que neste algoritmo implementei um laço de repetição `for`, onde ele percorre a lista citada anteriormente `([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`.

Em seguida defini um `if` onde verificará cada `elemento` da lista. Se o elemento é `maior` que `2` a variável contadora será `incrementada`. E, em seguida, exibe a quantidade de valores maiores que `2`.