# Filtrar lista python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso remover elementos de uma lista cuja referência de elementos para remoção estão em outra lista:

```
# Esta lista foi gerada por combinação
lista original=[
    (182361, 243148, 360624, 364188), 
    (182361, 243148, 360624, 547083), 
    (182361, 243148, 360624, 486296), 
    (182361, 243148, 360624, 368820), 
    (182361, 243148, 360624, 365256), 
    (182361, 243148, 364188, 547083), 
    (182361, 243148, 364188, 486296), 
    (182361, 243148, 364188, 368820), 
    (182361, 243148, 364188, 365256), 
    (182361, 243148, 547083, 486296), 
    (182361, 243148, 547083, 368820), 
    (182361, 243148, 547083, 365256), 
    (182361, 243148, 486296, 368820), 
    (182361, 243148, 486296, 365256), 
    (182361, 243148, 368820, 365256), 
    (182361, 360624, 364188, 547083), 
    (182361, 360624, 364188, 486296), 
    (182361, 360624, 364188, 368820), 
    (182361, 360624, 364188, 365256), 
    (182361, 360624, 547083, 486296), 
    (182361, 360624, 547083, 368820), 
    (182361, 360624, 547083, 365256), 
    (182361, 360624, 486296, 368820), 
    (182361, 360624, 486296, 365256), 
    (182361, 360624, 368820, 365256), 
    (182361, 364188, 547083, 486296), 
    (182361, 364188, 547083, 368820), 
    (182361, 364188, 547083, 365256), 
    (182361, 364188, 486296, 368820), 
    (182361, 364188, 486296, 365256), 
    (182361, 364188, 368820, 365256), 
    (182361, 547083, 486296, 368820), 
    (182361, 547083, 486296, 365256), 
    (182361, 547083, 368820, 365256), 
    (182361, 486296, 368820, 365256), 
    (243148, 360624, 364188, 547083), 
    (243148, 360624, 364188, 486296), 
    (243148, 360624, 364188, 368820), 
    (243148, 360624, 364188, 365256), 
    (243148, 360624, 547083, 486296), 
    (243148, 360624, 547083, 368820), 
    (243148, 360624, 547083, 365256), 
    (243148, 360624, 486296, 368820), 
    (243148, 360624, 486296, 365256), 
    (243148, 360624, 368820, 365256), 
    (243148, 364188, 547083, 486296), 
    (243148, 364188, 547083, 368820), 
    (243148, 364188, 547083, 365256), 
    (243148, 364188, 486296, 368820), 
    (243148, 364188, 486296, 365256), 
    (243148, 364188, 368820, 365256), 
    (243148, 547083, 486296, 368820), 
    (243148, 547083, 486296, 365256), 
    (243148, 547083, 368820, 365256), 
    (243148, 486296, 368820, 365256), 
    (360624, 364188, 547083, 486296), 
    (360624, 364188, 547083, 368820), 
    (360624, 364188, 547083, 365256), 
    (360624, 364188, 486296, 368820), 
    (360624, 364188, 486296, 365256), 
    (360624, 364188, 368820, 365256), 
    (360624, 547083, 486296, 368820), 
    (360624, 547083, 486296, 365256), 
    (360624, 547083, 368820, 365256), 
    (360624, 486296, 368820, 365256), 
    (364188, 547083, 486296, 368820), 
    (364188, 547083, 486296, 365256), 
    (364188, 547083, 368820, 365256), 
    (364188, 486296, 368820, 365256), 
    (547083, 486296, 368820, 365256)
]

# pares de elementos que preciso remover da lista original, ou seja, 
# se na lista original contiver qualquer desses pares que eles sejam 
# substituidos por zero.
lista de remoção=[
    [182361, 547083], 
    [243148, 486296], 
    [360624, 368820], 
    [364188, 365256]
]
```

Preciso que a saída seja uma lista composta de elementos em grupos de 4 (como na lista original), cujos elementos não contenham elementos da lista de referência de pares de remoção. Onde se exitir  a presença de um  par qualque da lista de remoção, que esse elemento seja substituído por zero.

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
lista final =[  (182361, 243148, 360624, 364188), (0, 243148, 360624, 0),   (182361, 0, 360624, 0),  (182361, 243148, 0, 0), (182361, 243148, 360624, 365256),  (0, 243148, 364188, 0),  (182361, 0, 364188, 0), 
    (182361, 243148, 364188, 368820), (182361, 243148, 0,0), 
    (0, 0, 0, 0),  (0, 243148, 0, 368820), (0, 243148, 0, 365256), 
    (182361, 0,0, 368820),  (182361, 0,0, 365256), (182361, 243148, 368820, 365256),  (0, 360624, 364188, 0), (182361, 360624, 364188, 486296), 
    (182361, 0, 364188, 0),  (182361, 360624, 0,0), (0, 360624, 0, 486296), 
    (0, 0, 0, 0),  (0, 360624, 0, 365256), (182361, 0, 486296, 0), 
    (182361, 360624, 486296, 365256), (182361, 0, 0, 365256), 
    (0, 364188, 0, 486296),  (0, 364188, 0, 368820),  (0, 0, 0, 0), 
    (182361, 364188, 486296, 368820),  (182361, 0, 486296, 0), 
    (182361, 0, 368820, 0),  (0,0, 486296, 368820), (0,0, 486296, 365256), 
    (0,0, 368820, 365256),  (182361, 486296, 368820, 365256), (243148, 360624, 364188, 547083),  (0, 360624, 364188, 0), (243148, 0, 364188, 0), 
    (243148, 360624, 0,0),  (0, 360624, 547083, 0), (243148, 0, 547083, 0), 
    (243148, 360624, 547083, 365256),  (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 360624, 0, 365256), 
    (243148, 0, 0, 365256),  (0, 364188, 547083, 0), (243148, 364188, 547083, 368820),  (243148, 0, 547083, 0), (0, 364188, 0, 368820), (0, 0, 0, 0), 
    (243148, 0, 368820, 0),  (0, 547083, 0, 368820),  (0, 547083, 0, 365256), 
    (243148, 547083, 368820, 365256),  (0,0, 368820, 365256), (360624, 364188, 547083, 486296), (0, 364188, 547083, 0),(360624, 0, 547083, 0), 
    (0, 364188, 486296, 0), (360624, 0, 486296, 365256), (0, 364188, 0, 365256), 
    (0, 547083, 486296, 0), (360624, 547083, 486296, 365256), (0, 547083, 0, 365256),  (0, 486296, 0, 365256), (364188, 547083, 486296, 368820), 
    (0, 547083, 486296, 0), (0, 547083, 368820, 0), (0, 486296, 368820, 0), 
    (547083, 486296, 368820, 365256)]
```

Esta seria a lista final após a exclusão dos pares de elementos da lista de exclusão.

Comment: Para facilitar o entendimento, você poderia editar sua resposta e adicionar um exemplo de um par que deve ser removido e mostrar como você gostaria que ficasse depois que o algoritmo executasse.

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda em alguma coisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190078/5878

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada com mais calma hoje..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lista_editada = []   # cria uma nova lista vazia
nao_foram_editados = [] # outra para os que nao foram editados
for grupo in lista_original:  # para cada grupo da lista
    foi_editado = False
    for teste in lista_remocao:  # testa todos da lista_remocao
        if all(item in grupo for item in teste): 
            # Achou o par! Removendo:
            grupo = tuple(0 if i in teste else i for i in grupo) 
            foi_editado = True

    lista_editada.append(grupo) # aqui adiciona todos os grupos
    if not foi_editado: # aqui adiciona os que nao sofreram edicao
         nao_foram_editados.append(grupo) 

print(lista_editada)
print(nao_foram_editados)
```

Comment: Oi Fernando. obrigado por responder,a lista de remoção contém os pares de valores que quero remover da lista original.pois os pares de valores  da lista de remoção são como combinações indesejadas presentes na lista original.

Comment: Nosklo,olá! dei uma olhada no link que vc.postou ,todavia, acho que o maior problema será fazer que o código leia o s elementos de remoção que estão em uma lista,vi que tem uma forma de remoção baseada em  um elemento externo ,o inteiro value,mas a questão é como fazer que o programa leias diversos pares de valores(value),para exclui-los na lista original?:refdef filter_by_generator(lista, value):
...   for i in lista:
...     if i != value: yield i
>>> lista = filter_by_generator(lista, 1)
>>> print(list(lista))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 15].

Comment: @JurandirPortela meu nome é nosklo ; a lista original não possui pares e sim tuplas contendo 4 valores cada... O código que eu coloquei remove o grupo de 4 valores da lista se ele contiver 2 valores da outra lista.

Comment: @JurandirPortela seria legal se você **editasse a pergunta** e colocasse um exemplo completo: lista de valores, lista de pares pra remover, e, principalmente, **o resultado que você queria que ficasse depois da remoção** - assim daria pra entender melhor

Comment: @JurandirPortela editei a resposta

Comment: Maravilha nosko,muito obrigado.Gostaria que fosse possível no futuro,Python converter-se num sistema algébrigo de cálculo, como o Máxima,esse código vai ajudar muito numa pesquisa que faço sobre números primos.

Comment: Como não sei programar estou usando uma linguagem visual chamada Pyno, que roda em python, ai estou aprendendo python para poder construir os blocos de código.Vi que existe o pymaxima, mas não sei como fazer para funcionar e seria de muita ajuda  poder executar os cálculos no maxima e trazer os resultados para o python, visto que infelizmente frações como 1/18512790 teem pouca precisão no python,e interfere muito nas relações de cálculo que estou construindo...Forte abraço a todos vocês que me ajudaram nessa questão...Obrigado!

Comment: @JurandirPortela esse comentário já está saindo do escopo da pergunta, mas, frações podem ser representadas com precisão no python usando o módulo `fractions` ou `decimal` dependendo do que quer fazer - ao usar `float`s para armazenar números perde precisão sim, mas não é um problema do python e sim da forma como `float`s são armazenadas na memória, o que afeta **todas as linguagens** de programação. Leia mais sobre isso nessa parte do tutorial básico: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Certo..Obrigado..

Comment: Olá.Gostaria de saber se é possivel no código  escrito por nosklo imprimir tambem a lista com valores que não foram zerados?Ou seja, a lista com as tuplas que não foram filtradas pela lista de remoção.

Comment: testei o código , mas verifiquei que das 70 combinações de entrada, sairam apenas 60,removi o comando all reapareceram as 70,mas ainda vou conferir a listagem gerada na saida.

Comment: @JurandirPortela Era pra sair a mesma quantidade de combinações, uma vez que o comando `append` está fora do `if`, ele sempre será executado ... tem certeza que colocou a identação exatamente como na minha resposta?

Comment: Vou verificar!Obrigado

Comment: Foi isso,identação,corrigir,está funcionando,mas teria como mostrar uma outra lista editada agora só com oas tuplas que não foram alteradas pela rotina de exclusão ou substituição zero?

Comment: @JurandirPortela sim, só usar outra lista - coloquei um exemplo na resposta

Comment: Maravilha!Obrigado.

Comment: já tentei onde é?

Comment: @JurandirPortela cara, aqui são comentários da resposta de outra pergunta, não é o lugar pra isso... Essa resposta mesmo é um exemplo do que você pediu! Ela cria duas listas, `lista_editada` e `nao_foram_editados`, e vai acumulando valores nelas com o método `.append()`