# Filtrar lista de objetos python

Tags: python, lista

Olá, sou novo em Python e estou com dúvidas para filtrar um objeto de uma lista.

Eu tenho a seguinte lista:

```
[{ ID: 1, Name: 'Teste 1' }, { ID: 2, Name: 'Teste 2' }]
```

E eu estou querendo realizar um filtro cujo ID é igua; a 1.

Eu encontrei na internet uma forma de filtrar que não está funcionando que é essa:

```
filter(None, lista)
```

Como posso realizar esse filtro?
Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Filtrar elementos de uma lista em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190078/filtrar-elementos-de-uma-lista-em-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função embutida [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter) está definida assim no manual da linguagem:

> **`filter(function, iterable)`**
> Constrói um *iterador* a partir dos elementos de *iterável* para os quais
> function retorna verdadeiro. O *iterável* pode ser uma sequência, um contêiner
> que com suporte a iteração, ou um iterador. Se function for None, a função
> identidade será usada, isto é, todos os elementos do *iterável* que são falsos
> são removidos.
> Note que `filter(function, iteravel)` é equivalente a expressão geradora:
>
> - `(item for item in iteravel if function(item))` se function não for `None`.
> - `(item for item in iteravel if item)` se function for `None`.

Então quando fez `filter(None, lista)` você informou ao interpretador que gostaria de obter o gerador `(item for item in lista if item)` que não realidade não filtra a `lista` apenas produz o gerador que reitera sobre seus itens.

Para realizara filtragem é preciso passa uma função de comparativa, como argumento no primeiro parâmetro. Essa deve retornar um [valor Booleano](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) onde:

- `True` informa que o item será aceito pelo filtro.
- `False` informa que o item será rejeitado pelo filtro.

Como filtro pode ser utilizada uma [função anônima](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

*Exemplo*: Numa lista de 100 dicionários `{"ID":inteiro , "Name": string}` cujo os `IDs` variam de 1 até 100, imprima apenas os dicionários cujo o `ID <= 10` e que `ID` seja par.

```
#Cria uma lista com dicionários cujo os ids vão de 1 até 100.
entrada =[{"ID": i + 1, "Name": f"Teste{i + 1}"} for i in range(100)]

#Cria o filtro que só retorna True se o ID de x for menor que 10 e a mesmo tempo o ID seja par.
filtro = lambda x: x["ID"] <= 10 and x["ID"] % 2 == 0

#Filtra a lista entrada.
filtrados = list(filter(filtro , entrada))

#Imprime o resultado.
print(filtrados)
```

Esse exemplo resultará em:

```
[{'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Teste2'}, 
 {'ID': 4, 'Name': 'Teste4'}, 
 {'ID': 6, 'Name': 'Teste6'}, 
 {'ID': 8, 'Name': 'Teste8'}, 
 {'ID': 10, 'Name': 'Teste10'}]
```

Voltando ao exemplo da pergunta onde você quer realizar uma filtragem do elemento cujo `ID` é igual a 1:

```
entrada =[{"ID": i + 1, "Name": f"Teste{i + 1}"} for i in range(100)]
    
#Filtro para aceitar apenas o x cujo o ID é um.
filtro = lambda x: x["ID"] == 1
    
filtrados = list(filter(filtro , entrada))


print(filtrados)
```

O que retorna:

```
[{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Teste1'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

primeiro crie um loop que observe todos os objetos dentro da lista

```
for i in lista:
```

depois teste se a propriedade ID é igual ao valor desejado (1 por ex.)

```
if i.ID == 1:
```

depois edite o nome deste objeto para "teste" por ex.

```
i.Name = "teste"
```

código completo:

```
 for i in lista:
    if i.ID == 1:
        i.Name = "teste"
```

Comment: Bem vindo à comunidade! Apesar de sua resposta estar correta, é desejável que haja a explicação do `porquê` da sua solução, para que a resposta fique mais completa e sirva de referência para outras pessoas.

Comment: ok, perdao vou reescrever a resposta

Answer (score 1):

A função `filter()` aplica uma função a um objeto iterável.

No seu caso, teríamos algo mais ou menos assim:

```py
def filtro(x):
    if x['ID'] == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

lista = [{ ID: 1, Name: 'Teste 1' }, { ID: 2, Name: 'Teste 2' }]

resultado = filter(filtro, lista)

for _ in resultado:
    print(_)

{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Teste 1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a expressão lambda e testar se o ID é 1

```
lista = [{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Teste 1' }, {'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Teste 2' }]

filtrado = filter(lambda x: x['ID'] == 1, lista)
```

Saída

```
[f for f in filtrado]
[{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Teste 1'}]
```